# How to subtract a value from one table while adding to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, I have 2 scripts running on same db but each has their own tables (like users, posts, etc etc) and they have points system.

Now, what I want to do is to make possible to send points from one to another.
I have created a simple form with name and points for it to be filled and than when submitted would send to another page that would process the informations, taking the given amount away from the user (will check session for that) and than sending it to the given name (that is registered in the other script).

Ok, when it process the points are taken away (or give a "not enough points" error if they do not have enough points) but the points are not credited to the other account.
Is it possible to have this solved?

Here goes the code snippet:

```
// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('mods/points'); 
$pointst1 = request_var('pointst', 0);
$bsname1 = request_var('bsname', 0);

if ( $user->data['user_points'] < $pointst1 ){
echo "<b>You don't have enough points</b>";
}

else {
remove_points($user->data['user_id'], $pointst1);
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points = (points + $pointst1) WHERE name = '$bsname'");
echo "<b>Points tranferred!</b>";
};

?>
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_query` in new applications, use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead. Also, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) before you do some serious harm.

Comment: You should look up the second user by name if that's all you have and then use the user id in your update query instead of name. You should also wrap your $pointst1 in intval() to enforce a number and then check for zero or a negative number before updating.

Comment: what does `mysql_error` say if you call it after each request? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: I think you have the possibility here of a name conflict. If user 1 wants to send point to "John Smith", you could potentially have several. How do you know which one he means? I think you need some way to uniquely identify the recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things.

First, I recommend you check out this site on handling SQL Commits.  That will help ensure you don't remove points from one user, and have them NOT added to the other user. Which can happen in your current code example

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.transaction.php

Second, it seems as though this part is passing the php variable as a text

> mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points = (points + $pointst1) WHERE name = '$bsname'");
>   echo "**Points tranferred!**"

You might want to change it to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points = (points + {$pointst1} ) WHERE name = {$bsname}");
echo "<b>Points tranferred!</b>"
```

I'm not a PHP programmer, so you can check my logic here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Hope it helps

Comment: Good suggestion to use a transaction. I agree!

Comment: thank you for the answers, nothing seems to work this out tho. I might try some cookies and page forwarding to see what I get.